# Making Transaction from remote device (e.g. Mobile) to make Transaction or call data from Blockain

Tags: blockchain

I was thinking of developing a mobile application which can make transaction in private network nodes of which are located at a server.
How this objective can be achieved?
What should be the technologies I should learn to implement?

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about "private network nodes which are located at a server"? Blockchain is a distributed system, so nodes should be in different hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are talking about developing a permissioned Blockchain, i.e. a private network where everyone can't access. So, if I were you, I'd learn about the Fabric project by Hyperledger, which is an implementation of Blockchain for permissioned networks. You have more information about it [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Fabric allows you to create a permissioned Blockchain. Then, you will develop the clients that will call the Blockchain. In the Blockchain, you deploy your smartcontract, i.e. the code that you want to be executed.